# How to use class values as default with multiple subclasses?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sure this is something very simple, but I'm new.

I have a set of classes. Let's call

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

class Mix: 
    def BMethod(self):
        return '{0} is right'

class Child(Parent, Mix):
    def __init__(self, name, color, type):
        self.type = 'AAA'
        self.color = 'None'
        super(Child,self).__init__(name,color)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} is a {1} {2}.'.format(self.name,self.color,self.type)

class ChildSubType(Child, Mix):
    def __init__(self, name, color, type):
        color = 'None'
        kind = super().kind
        super(ChildSubType,self).__init__(name,color,type)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} is not a {1} {2}".format(self.name,self.color.self.type)


childsubtype = ChildSubType(
    "Name1"
    ,"White"
)

print(childsubtype)
```

When I run this code, I get an error that says "`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'type'`"

Essentially, my goal is that for ChildSubType, I can only be required to put in the Name, and if I don't put in a Color or a Type, then it will default it to the value from the ChildSubType class for the color, and it will default it to the Child class for the type.

I'm not entirely sure how to achieve this.

I would assume that it has something to do with the `def __init__` method in the ChildSubType, but I'm not 100% clear on what that is supposed to be doing either. At this point, I'm basically following along with the instructions, and have hit this road block.

For what it's worth, I also tried running it with just `Child` without using `ChildSubType` and ran into the same error. I guess I just don't know how to use the default value from inside the class.

EDIT: 
Alright, I think I've got it working. I updated the code to give it a default value as suggested in the comments.

Here's what I changed:

```
Class Child(Parent, Mix):
    def __init__(self, name, color, **type = 'AAA'**):
        self.type = 'AAA'
        self.color = 'None'
        super(Child,self).__init__(name,color)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} is a {1} {2}.'.format(self.name,self.color,self.type)

class ChildSubType(Child, Mix):
    def __init__(self, name, color, **type = super(type)**):
        color = 'None'
        kind = super().kind
        super(ChildSubType,self).__init__(name,color,type)
```

Comment: I think you can use a keyword argument here `__init__(..., type='default')`

Comment: That would make sense... However, if I don't definite it in ChildSubType, how would I call the default value from the Child class?

Comment: The default `type` gets passed via your `super` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your `__init__` method in contains 3 initialization variables but you are passing only 2 while making an object. I would recommend using a default value as follows :

```
def __init__(self, name, color='None', type=None):
```

Comment: Indeed, I would just refrain from overriding the built-in `type`